# Thymeleaf + SpringBoot + JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app. with Thymeleaf and JQuery:

```
<form action="#" th:id="myForm" th:action="@{/home.html}" th:object="${searchForm}" method="post" >

            
                <input id="gre"             type="hidden" th:field="*{gre}" />
<a href="#" onclick="$('form#gre').val('true'); $('form#myForm').submit();" >Studio</a>
```

but the value of gre after submit is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way is using javascript i.e : set value of input using `document.getElementById('gre').value="somehting"` and then use `.submit()` to submit form.

***Demo Code*** :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="myForm" th:action="@{/home.html}" th:object="${searchForm}" method="post">
  <input id="gre" type="text" th:field="*{gre}" />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('gre').value ='true';document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); ">Studio</a>
```